# Using R.NET.Community in .NET Core 2.0 Preview 1

Tags: c#, r, .net-core

For a while, I've been hoping to use [R.NET.Community](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET.Community/) in a .NET Core app. Obviously though with the NuGet package not having been ported to .NET Core, that's been a non-starter. However, with the [.NET Core 2.0 Preview 1 announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/10/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-1/) that you can reference .NET Framework libraries from .NET Core, I gave this another go:

```
using RDotNet;

namespace RDotNetCore2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
            var engine = REngine.GetInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Creating this as a .NET Core 2.0 app in the new Visual Studio 2017 Preview, this at least gets as far as compiling and running, but errors at the `GetInstance` call:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or this just one of those bits which isn't supported in .NET Core (which I suspect may be likely due to the fact that CAS isn't supported on .NET Core)?

Comment: You can track the current GitHub issue for NET Core support, https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/issues/40

Comment: Been following that issue for a long time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is a Framework *version* problem?

There isn't a `System.Security.Permissions` file in the 4.x version of .net (although there is a [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions(v=vs.110).aspx)). There *is* a dll with this name in .net Core 2.0, though (containing, for example, the [`PrincipalPermissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.principalpermission?view=netcore-2.0) class. In .net 4.7, this class is implemented in `mscorlib.dll`).

It's probably worth having a look at your project references before you conclude that this isn't going to work. If you can add a reference there to the dll (which presumably you should have had installed with the Core 2.0 runtime), that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the latest System.Security.Permissions from NuGet fixed this issue for me in a fresh 2.1 console application.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your dependencies. You still need to install R.Net [R.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET/). This will install the missing security files. I got the same error you received then I installed R.Net and the missing files and all is fine now.