# Using R.NET with ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, r, .net-core

I am currently attempting to be run some R in the context of a Dot Net Core C# console application. I have created a new .NET Core 2.1 console application, then added R.Net (which is a Dot Net Framework application, 4.6.1, yes I know, it's not dot net core). I then ran the application, and it complained about a missing Security assembly: System.Security.Permissions. Someone else has tried to do what I want, but with an older preview version of dot net core. They went to nuget and installed the System.Security.Permissions package, and managed to get past the security issue. That Security issue is found on Stack Overflow [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939463/using-r-net-community-in-net-core-2-0-preview-1)

This is what my code looks like:

```
namespace RDotNetCore2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
            var engine = REngine.GetInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it gets past the "REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables" line, but it fails on the "var engine = REngine.GetInstance()" line with a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception.

I have also added a dot net standard 2 Class library, made it target dot net framework 4.6.1, installed the R.net and security package, and then called the same bit of code but in a class this time, and I've got the same problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think R.Net Community is compatible with .net core.  change your app to be .net framework v4.6.1

Comment: It's a bit hard to do that. The application I intend to add it to is now a substantial dot net core 2.1 app.

Comment: That link suggests that they got it working

Comment: i see - have you tried to compile the nuget library yourself to target on .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later?

Comment: Yes, I've now tried that. I have tried RDotNet and now Spread.R. Spread.R has had some work done to it to make it work in dot net standard 2, so was the most promising, but it still caused me problems because the interoperability doesn't seem to work properly. It crashes out on a null reference exception when attempting to REngine.GetInstance().

Comment: Spread.R fails on the line: this.sexp = (SEXPREC)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(SEXPREC)); which is some sort of interop issue, while trying to initialise the engine.

Comment: Ok I've set up a hello world Dot Net Framework application and run it, and its also failing. I suspect now that I have a problem with environment variables.

Comment: I found the cause of the NullReferenceException. RDotNet doesn't support R 3.5.0 yet. You have to uninstall 3.5.0 and install 3.4.4 to get it working. Ok, now to test dot net core.